# how to make text field non editable at first launch of app

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I want to make textfield non editable when application first time launched.
And I am having a UIBarbutton item by tapping it, it will make textfield editable.
i am trying below code but not working .

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(edit == NO){
   textField.enabled = NO;
}
    if(edit == YES){
    textField.enabled = NO;
  }
 return YES;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this method

```
-(Void)viewwillappers
 {
   [textfield setEnable:NO];
 }
```

after click bar button set it to yes in Button Click method.

Comment: This method [textfield setEnable:NO]; should place in viewdidLoad according to virendra requirement.

Comment: Ya @jay you are right but if virendra move to another view and come back and he want same thing then vewdidload doesn't work ,both are same so not worried about that thing or this one more comfort for him.

Comment: so are you tap the negative to me in reputation arrow?

Comment: guys my textfield are in tableview cell ...i am using uitableviewcell sub class for that but i am still unable to call setEnable ......

Comment: i never tap negative down arrow to anyone or even you

Comment: where you try to call setEnable.are you have another viewcontroller for uitableviewcell?

Comment: textfield_in_tableview_cell_Cell * celltextfield = [textfield_in_tableview_cell_Cell alloc];
 
 [celltextfield.rightTextField setEnabled:NO]; i am doing this way but still textfield not disabled

Comment: yah i am having different view controller for uitableviewcell

Comment: @virendra you create sub class of uitableview cell right?then why you use this much long procedure for add the textfield in tableview cell and why you are not trying dynamic textfield in tableviewcell?

Comment: So I show you one code if you using different class of uitableviewcell.But if you have only one textfield in table view create it dynamically in tableview I think that will be more better for you.

Comment: how can i add textfield dynamically

Comment: I show you that also wait and i show you tableviewcell code also in above.

Comment: See below my dynamic textfield answer and try yourself also that will increase your experience level.

Comment: @virendra if you got your answer then increase the arrow reputation and answer be tick.Thanks

Comment: dynamic textfield implementation working fine ........but setEnabled still not working

Answer (score 2):

```
txtfld.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
// perform changes and enable afterwards
txtfld.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
-(Void)viewwillapper

{

[textfield setuserintractionEnable:yes];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` delegate for this,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [textfield setEnable:NO];
 }
```

And write `[textfield setEnable:YES];` in the bar button's click method,

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender
  {
    [textfield setEnable:YES];
  }
```

If you use the above code, then if you navigate to another view (detailed view) and come back then also the textField will be disabled. If you don't want that, then use the following code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [textfield setEnable:NO];
 }
```

For more about the view controller delegates: [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
             reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
            autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[Players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

playername=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, 280, 30)];  
playername.placeholder=@"Player";
playername.delegate=self;
playername.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
 // playername.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
[cell.contentView addSubview:playername];
 return cell;
}
```

use this for dynamic textfield.

Comment: Why are you posting answers more than once?

Comment: This does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're using Storyboard, you can simply just uncheck the "enabled" checkbox of the TextField. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

in XIB , for textrField's properties, uncheck the "user interaction enabled"

.Now on the Bar button's click event use this:

```
   [textfield setEnable:NO];
```

Benifits:

when you again load this view.At first that textField will be dissabled.

So it will do as you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"tblCellView";

PlayerDetailsCell *cell = (PlayerDetailsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PlayerDetailsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tblCell;
}
return cell; 
}
```

Use this code in your table view and call your uitableviewcell class.like I am calling(playerdetailscell)

Comment: Why are you posting answers more than once?

Comment: because He have more then one question at a time.